# Would base.OnLoad() cause an infinite loop if called in page_load event?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms, page-lifecycle

A member of my team went through a few pages in our ASP.NET web application and changed some OnLoad overrides to page_load events, but he did not remove the call to base.OnLoad().

This:

```
Public void override OnLoad()
{
    //stuff
    base.OnLoad();
}
```

To this:

```
Public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //stuff
    base.OnLoad();
}
```

Note: I apologize if there are syntax errors, I am not on a computer with the actual source code.

When we pushed out code to the live server we started having issues with the IIS app_pool crashing every 45 mins to an hour. We are still not entirely sure this was the issue but I am curious where page_load events get invoked from. Do they get invoked from the OnLoad method in the system.web.ui.page? If so then I have the opinion this was causing an infinite loop and eventually running out of memory and crashing the app_pool.

Could this be the cause of our troubles?

Comment: Surely if it was casing an infinite loop opening the page would cause a stack overflow and  you would know straight away.

Comment: I know we didn't need it. I'm only curious if that could cause the app pool to crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`base.OnLoad();` causes the `Load` event to be raised.  That would then cause your page's `OnLoad` event handler to be raised, which contains the call to `OnLoad` again.  The code you've posted is indeed incorrect.

The [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) article on MSDN is a good read for explaining how page loads and other events work.

Answer (score 0):

Even if it doesn't cause infinite loop, the decision of change from overriding the base virtual method to handling events, is not an intelligent one. I would  suggest you to override, instead of worrying about infinite loops. The fact that it makes you worry, is an indication that overriding is a better choice.

Read **Item 30 : Prefer Overrides to Event Handlers**  from **Effective C#** by  Bill Wagner.